# preg_match question, how to do this?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Say I have the following:

```
$var = "127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data. 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=19.5 ms --- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics --- 1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 19.548/19.548/19.548/0.000 ms ";
```

How can I return so it just says

```
$var2 = "19.5";
```

So it basically grabs whats in this part: `time=19.5 ms ---`

Thank you

**EDIT**

I think I have figured it out myself:

```
$var = "127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data. 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=19.5 ms --- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics --- 1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 19.548/19.548/19.548/0.000 ms";

$var2 = preg_match("/time=(.*) ms ---/", $var, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

I don't know if this is the right way to do it, but it seems to work?

Comment: Is your number always at the same position? you could use substring

Comment: I have looked at the string wtwice - cannot see 10.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$var = "127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data. 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=19.5 ms --- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics --- 1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 19.548/19.548/19.548/0.000 ms ";
if(preg_match('/time=(\d+\.\d+)/', $var, $match)) {
  $var2 = $match[1];
  echo $var2;
}
```

which will echo:

```
19.5
```

`$match[1]` will contain the entire match (`time=19.5`), in your case, and `$match[1]` contains match group 1 from the pattern: which is the number `19.5`.

Comment: This works also, I edited my question with something which seems to work but I'd trust yours over mine as I'm a beginner to regex :) Thank you.

Comment: If there's a second `ms ---` in your line (after the `time= ...` occurrence), then the  `.*` will consume too much. It's better to describe what you want to match as precise as possible, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match("/time=([\d.]+).ms/",$var,$matches);
//var_dump($matches)
//$match[1] now holds the 19.5
?>
```

Enjoy

Comment: This will hold only the `19` not the whole number `19.5`

Comment: Updated the regex, now it holds the complete number ;)

Answer (score 1):

This could do it with `preg_match`:

```
if (preg_match("/time=(.*?) ms/", $line, $m)) {
  $time = (float) $m[1];
}
```

Or with `explode`:

```
$fields = explode("=", $line);
$time = (float) $fields[4];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could retrieve this with the following pattern:

```
preg_match('/time=([^ ]+) /',$matches);
echo $matches[1]; // 19.5
```

Matches after `time=` at least one character (`+`) that isn't a space (`[^ ]`).

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex in your `preg_match` call

```
time=([\d\.]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$var="127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data. 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=19.5 ms --- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics --- 1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 19.548/19.548/19.548/0.000 ms ";

preg_match("/time=([0-9.]+)/", $var, $matches);

$var2 = $matches[1];

echo $var2;

?>
```

Edit: Or you can edit the regex to:

```
preg_match("/time\s*=\s*([0-9.]+)/", $var, $matches);
```

So that it matches "time=xx.x" or "time = xx.x".